# what was a syntax for looping product in a array ruby on rails using spree commerce

Tags: spree

I want to create an array and loop all products and do not insert the products which are sold or not in stock and then in second loop add the products which are not in stock or sold out in same array. so all products which are not in stock will go at end.

so i need help to achieve it in spree eCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

SCM, If you would like to receive answers faster you should visit official Spree commerce slack. There is over 5000 members that are active in terms of development. I'm more than sure they will be able to help you with any issues.